# Can ffmpeg show a progress bar?

Tags: ffmpeg, progress-bar

I am converting a .avi file to .flv file using ffmpeg. As it takes a long time to convert a file I would like to display a progress bar. Can someone please guide me on how to go about the same.

I know that ffmpeg somehow has to output the progress in a text file and I have to read it using ajax calls. But how do I get ffmpeg to output the progress to the text file?

Answer (score 37):

I've been playing around with this for a few days. That "ffmpegprogress" thing helped, but it was very hard to get to work with my set up, and hard to read the code.

In order to show the progress of ffmpeg you need to do the following:

1. run the ffmpeg command from php without it waiting for a response (for me, this was the hardest part)
2. tell ffmpeg to send it's output to a file
3. from the front end (AJAX, Flash, whatever) hit either that file directly or a php file that can pull out the progress from ffmpeg's output.

Here's how I solved each part:

1.
I got the following idea from "ffmpegprogress". This is what he did: one PHP file calls another through an http socket. The 2nd one actually runs the "exec" and the first file just hangs up on it. For me his implementation was too complex. He was using "fsockopen". I like CURL. So here's what I did:

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/path/to/exec/exec.php";
curl_setopt($curlH, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$postData = "&cmd=".urlencode($cmd);
$postData .= "&outFile=".urlencode("path/to/output.txt");
curl_setopt($curlH, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlH, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

curl_setopt($curlH, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// # this is the key!
curl_setopt($curlH, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curlH);
```

Setting CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 1 means it will wait 1 second for a response. Preferably that would be lower. There is also the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS which takes milliseconds, but it didn't work for me.

After 1 second, CURL hangs up, but the exec command still runs. Part 1 solved.

BTW - A few people were suggesting using the "nohup" command for this. But that didn't seem to work for me.

*ALSO! Having a php file on your server that can execute code directly on the command line is an obvious security risk. You should have a password, or encode the post data in some way.

2.
The "exec.php" script above must also tell ffmpeg to output to a file. Here's code for that:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i path/to/input.mov path/to/output.flv 1> path/to/output.txt 2>&1");
```

Note the "1> path/to/output.txt 2>&1". I'm no command line expert, but from what I can tell this line says "send normal output to this file, AND send errors to the same place". Check out this url for more info: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

3.
From the front end call a php script giving it the location of the output.txt file. That php file will then pull out the progress from the text file. Here's how I did that:

```
// # get duration of source
preg_match("/Duration: (.*?), start:/", $content, $matches);

$rawDuration = $matches[1];

// # rawDuration is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
$ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawDuration));
$duration = floatval($ar[0]);
if (!empty($ar[1])) $duration += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
if (!empty($ar[2])) $duration += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;


// # get the current time
preg_match_all("/time=(.*?) bitrate/", $content, $matches); 

$last = array_pop($matches);
// # this is needed if there is more than one match
if (is_array($last)) {
    $last = array_pop($last);
}

$curTime = floatval($last);


// # finally, progress is easy
$progress = $curTime/$duration;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I'd like to add something I discovered today. It seems along with ffmpeg comes ffprobe which can be used to get info in std output ("ffmpeg -i {file}" actually exits with an error code so you'll have to pipe output using 2>1 to get the info). so, have at it:
`ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -i file.mp4 -show_streams`

Answer (score 35):

There is an [article](http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/encoding-media-files-in-ruby-using-ffmpeg-mencoder-with-progress-tracking/) in Russian which describes how to solve your problem.

The point is to catch `Duration` value before encoding and to catch `time=...` values during encoding.

```
--skipped--
Duration: 00:00:24.9, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 331 kb/s
--skipped--
frame=   41 q=7.0 size=     116kB time=1.6 bitrate= 579.7kbits/s
frame=   78 q=12.0 size=     189kB time=3.1 bitrate= 497.2kbits/s
frame=  115 q=13.0 size=     254kB time=4.6 bitrate= 452.3kbits/s
--skipped--
```

Comment: I went to the article expecting to struggle a little with the Russian but it was  surprisingly easy to read.

Comment: I think the command on the article is like this `ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -vcodec xvid -acodec mp3 -ab 96 output.avi > output.txt`

Answer (score 34):

It’s very simple if you use the pipeview command. To do this, transform

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi {arguments}
```

to

```
pv input.avi | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -v warning {arguments}
```

No need to get into coding!

Comment: I like this answer. It's very elegant. A relevant argument for `pv` is `-n` to only get the numeric progress in percent.

Comment: Beware that `ffmpeg` will fail to encode from `stdin` for video that are not streamable like a `*.mov` file where the meta data is at the end. The reason is that `ffmpeg` cannot seek to the meta data on the pipe. You'd have to `qt-faststart` every inputfile before you can pipe it into `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I thought of using pv first, then after realizing that my ffmpeg doesn't write any useful vstats because of a particular video filter being used I looked closer at pv and found that it does exactly what I want. I'm just using times in the format string and additional text `pv -F "some additional info here %t %e" "${video}"`, that's all I needed.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to add the above code to mine, however, no success. Andy advice please `for /R %%f IN (*.mkv) DO ffmpeg -v warning -hide_banner -stats -i "%%f" -map 0 -c copy "%%~nf.mp4"`

Comment: Using ```-v quiet``` instead of -v warning so that there is no ffmpeg output and only the pv output is displayed

Answer (score 23):

You can do it with `ffmpeg`'s  `-progress` argument and `nc`

```
WATCHER_PORT=9998

DURATION= $(ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -show_entries "stream=duration" \
    -of compact $INPUT_FILE | sed 's!.*=\(.*\)!\1!g')

nc -l $WATCHER_PORT | while read; do
    sed -n 's/out_time=\(.*\)/\1 of $DURATION/p')
done &

ffmpeg -y -i $INPUT_FILE -progress localhost:$WATCHER_PORT $OUTPUT_ARGS
```

Comment: This looks like it leads to the best solution. You can pipe the progress information via `ffmpeg -v warning -progress /dev/stdout -i in.mp4 out.mp4` to `stdout` in order to get progress updates once per second. If you only need a percentage you'd `ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format in.mp4` for the `duration`  in seconds before starting the encoding and then `| awk -F"=" '/out_time_ms/{print $2}'` to only get the current duration in ms where `progress = total_duration * 100 * 1000 / current_duration`.

Comment: I didn't know you could route progress to a file; if that's the case you could just make a fifo out of `sed` and be on your way.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to create a named pipe and call `ffmpeg` and `sed | grep | awk | whatever` separately to get `ffmpeg`'s return code. Furthermore I send `ffmpeg`'s stdout to a logfile so that in case of an error (code > 0) you have something to look at. My wip command currently looks something like `ffmpeg -v warning -progress /dev/stdout -y -i $source $encodingOptions $target >>$logFile | grep --line-buffered out_time_ms`.

Answer (score 20):

FFmpeg uses stdout for outputing media data and stderr for logging/progress information. You just have to redirect stderr to a file or to stdin of a process able to handle it.

With a unix shell this is something like:

```
ffmpeg {ffmpeg arguments} 2> logFile
```

or

```
ffmpeg {ffmpeg arguments} 2| processFFmpegLog
```

Anyway, you have to run ffmpeg as a separate thread or process.

Comment: Were I to ask the question, I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @mouviciel, do you know how I can achieve this in .NET? I tried what you said and it doesn't print out a file, also How can I get notified for when the file is changed?

Comment: Thank you for specifying the output with relation to stdout and stderr

Answer (score 17):

Sadly, `ffmpeg` itself still cannot show a progress bar – also, many of the aforementioned bash- or python-based stop-gap solutions have become dated and nonfunctional.

**Thus, i recommend giving the brand-new [ffmpeg-progressbar-cli](https://github.com/sidneys/ffmpeg-progressbar-cli) a try:**

[image: ffmpeg-progressbar-cli screencast]

It's a wrapper for the `ffmpeg` executable, showing a **colored, centered progress bar** and the remaining time.

Also, it's open-source, based on Node.js and actively developed, handling most of the mentioned quirks (full disclosure: i'm its current lead developer).

Comment: 2020 update, the longer considered active. last commit to master in Nov 2018, 9 open issues, 3 open pull requests.

Comment: Also now ffmpeg has its own progress bar

Comment: @TanishqBanyal what is the correct flag to pass for ffmpeg's progress bar? I can't find the option in the documentation/internet?

Comment: Not a progress bar, but you can pipe `-progress - -y` before the output. e.g. `ffmpeg -i ..... -progress - -y output.mp4`

Answer (score 12):

If you just need hide all info and show default progress like ffmpeg in last line, you can use `-stats` option:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -hide_banner -stats ${your_params}
```

Answer (score 6):

I found `ffpb` Python package (`pip install ffpb`) that passes arguments transparently to FFmpeg. Due to it's robustness, it doesn't need much maintenance. The last release is from Apr 29, 2019.

[image]

https://github.com/althonos/ffpb

Comment: I found this to be the easiest and least complex solution to show a prograss bar for ffmpeg (confirmed to work absolutely great With MacOS Ventura!)

Answer (score 3):

javascript should tell php to start converting [1] and then do [2] ...

---

**[1]** *php:* start conversion and write status to file (see above):

```
exec("ffmpeg -i path/to/input.mov path/to/output.flv 1>path/to/output.txt 2>&1");
```

---

For the second part we need **just javascript** to read the file.
The following example uses dojo.request for AJAX, but you could use jQuery or vanilla or whatever as well :

**[2]** *js:* grab the progress from the file:

```
var _progress = function(i){
    i++;
    // THIS MUST BE THE PATH OF THE .txt FILE SPECIFIED IN [1] : 
    var logfile = 'path/to/output.txt';

/* (example requires dojo) */

request.post(logfile).then( function(content){
// AJAX success
    var duration = 0, time = 0, progress = 0;
    var resArr = [];

    // get duration of source
    var matches = (content) ? content.match(/Duration: (.*?), start:/) : [];
    if( matches.length>0 ){
        var rawDuration = matches[1];
        // convert rawDuration from 00:00:00.00 to seconds.
        var ar = rawDuration.split(":").reverse();
        duration = parseFloat(ar[0]);
        if (ar[1]) duration += parseInt(ar[1]) * 60;
        if (ar[2]) duration += parseInt(ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

        // get the time 
        matches = content.match(/time=(.*?) bitrate/g);
        console.log( matches );

        if( matches.length>0 ){
            var rawTime = matches.pop();
            // needed if there is more than one match
            if (lang.isArray(rawTime)){ 
                rawTime = rawTime.pop().replace('time=','').replace(' bitrate',''); 
            } else {
                rawTime = rawTime.replace('time=','').replace(' bitrate','');
            }

            // convert rawTime from 00:00:00.00 to seconds.
            ar = rawTime.split(":").reverse();
            time = parseFloat(ar[0]);
            if (ar[1]) time += parseInt(ar[1]) * 60;
            if (ar[2]) time += parseInt(ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

            //calculate the progress
            progress = Math.round((time/duration) * 100);
        }

        resArr['status'] = 200;
        resArr['duration'] = duration;
        resArr['current']  = time;
        resArr['progress'] = progress;

        console.log(resArr);

        /* UPDATE YOUR PROGRESSBAR HERE with above values ... */

        if(progress==0 && i>20){
            // TODO err - giving up after 8 sec. no progress - handle progress errors here
            console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"there is no progress while we tried to encode the video" }'); 
            return;
        } else if(progress<100){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ _progress(i); }, 400);
        }
    } else if( content.indexOf('Permission denied') > -1) {
        // TODO - err - ffmpeg is not executable ...
        console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"ffmpeg : Permission denied, either for ffmpeg or upload location ..." }');    
    } 
},
function(err){
// AJAX error
    if(i<20){
        // retry
        setTimeout(function(){ _progress(0); }, 400);
    } else {
        console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"there is no progress while we tried to encode the video" }');
        console.log( err ); 
    }
    return; 
});

}
setTimeout(function(){ _progress(0); }, 800);
```

Comment: You above code is giving below error. Please reply if possible.
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR**

Comment: @sebilasse correct your code because it brings errors

Answer (score 2):

Had problems with the second php part. So I am using this instead:

```
$log = @file_get_contents($txt);
preg_match("/Duration:([^,]+)/", $log, $matches);
list($hours,$minutes,$seconds,$mili) = split(":",$matches[1]);
$seconds = (($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds);
$seconds = round($seconds);

$page = join("",file("$txt"));
$kw = explode("time=", $page);
$last = array_pop($kw);
$values = explode(' ', $last);
$curTime = round($values[0]);
$percent_extracted = round((($curTime * 100)/($seconds)));
```

Outputs perfectly.

Would like to see something for multiple uploads for another progress bar. This passing for the current file for one percentage. Then an overall progress bar. Almost there.

Also, if people are having a hard time getting:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i path/to/input.mov path/to/output.flv 1> path/to/output.txt 2>&1");
```

To work.

Try:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i path/to/input.mov path/to/output.flv 1>path/to/output.txt 2>&1");
```

"**1> path**" to "**1>path**" OR "**2> path**" to "**2>path**"

Took me awhile to figure it out. FFMPEG kept failing. Worked when I changed to no space.

Answer (score 2):

These answers that use multiple tools/consoles are complicating things too much.
`pv` is a good option but has the noted drawbacks of missing non-senquential data.
Just use the `progress` utility:  Run ffmpeg as normal then in another console monitor with `progress -m -c ffmpeg`

Answer (score 2):

By taking the progress bar from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63003551/3868690), I create a simple script that shows the actual frame of the video being encoded and shows a progress bar at the bottom of it... at the same time that ffmpeg encodes the video, of course.

[image]

First, we have to get duration, width and height from the video, to create the bar. But, as `color` filter can't get this information from the file, we have to get them first with `ffprobe`. Then, we use them with ffmpeg.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

video_duration=`ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1"`
video_width=`ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width    -of csv=p=0:s=x "$1"`
video_height=`ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v -show_entries stream=height   -of csv=p=0:s=x "$1"`
five_percent=`expr $video_height / 20`

#echo $video_duration
#echo $video_width
#echo $video_height
#echo $five_percent

ffmpeg -i "$1" -filter_complex "color=c=red:s='$video_width'x$five_percent[bar];[0][bar]overlay=-w+(w/$video_duration)*t:H-h:shortest=1[bar]" "$2" -map [bar] -f xv display
```

Then, use script as:

```
sh encode_with_bar.sh video_in.mkv video_out.mp4
```

**Performance:** the filter used is very simple... but everything added consumes additional CPU. Testing a 10MB video file in my computer, this is the difference:

- Without script: 14.46 seconds
- With script: 17.05 seconds (18% more)

Yes, almost 20% more. For short videos, it's nice. For larger files, probably it's not a good idea .

Answer (score 1):

Calling php's system function blocks that thread, so you'll need to spawn off 1 HTTP request for performing the conversion, and another polling one for reading the txt file, that's being generated.

Or, better yet, clients submit the video for conversion and then another process is made responsible for performing the conversion.  That way the client's connection won't timeout while waiting for the system call to terminate.  Polling is done in the same way as above.

Comment: But why use a text file? there has got to be a better way. Wouldn't you have to make a new text file for every upload?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

I use [ffpb](https://github.com/althonos/ffpb) and python subprocess to tracking ffmpeg progress. Then I push status to a database (ex: Redis) for display a progress bar on website.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'ffpb -i 400MB.mp4 400MB.avi'

process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True,
    encoding='utf-8',
    errors='replace'
)

while True:
    realtime_output = process.stdout.readline()

    if realtime_output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break

    if realtime_output:
        print(realtime_output.strip(), flush=True)
        print('Push status to Redis...')
```

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation of [this library](https://github.com/sidneys/ffmpeg-progressbar-cli/blob/master/lib/main.js#L132) I see that implementation should follow these steps:

1. Calc result duration. E.g. get initial duration (substract any trim seconds if required):

```bash
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 input.mkv
```

Result must be parsed as float and stored, e.g. in JavaScript:

```js
const duration = parseFloat(result);
```

2. In task - specify additional flag, so ffmpeg will output processed duration:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -progress pipe:1 ...
```

Or the same but pipe to stderr:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -progress pipe:2 ...
```

3. Extract processed duration (from stdout or stderr), e.g. in JavaScript:

```js
const matchedResult = chunkResult.match(/out_time_ms=(\d+)/);
if (Array.isArray(matchedResult)) {
  const currentTimeMs = Math.round(Number(matchedResult[1]) / 1000000);
}
```

4. Compare processed duration with total duration

```js
currentTimeMs/duration
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple &… Here's a brief summary of the possibilities for using a progress bar.

No problem with *pv* ([istefani's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30482214/3585282)) for converting, e.g. YouTube videos. Not working for videos downloaded from Odysee though. I've got this error message:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fee39005400] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fee39005400] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 604 kb/s): unspecified pixel format Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
```

I ended up using *ffpb*, which still works great for me; no issues so far.

Using `progress -m -c ffmpeg …` is interesting, but one needs to open another console to run it after executing the normal *ffmpeg* command in the first console (not convenient if running from a shell script).

*ffmpeg-progress-yield* seems to be an excellent alternative to *ffpb*, but does not show (at least, for me) the name of the video being converted; it shows “test” instead of the actual filename.

Finally, *ffmpeg-progressbar-cli* is very similar to *ffpb* and *ffmpeg-progress-yield*, but apparently, is no longer maintained; I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

## Docker

To convert WMA/MP3 files to static movie (to upload them to youtube) I try to use docker jrottenberg/ffmpeg. At the begining it seems that none of above solutions works - but when I run docker compose using `run` instead `up` then [Geograph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55853767/860099) solution works :)

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    musicToVideo:
        image: jrottenberg/ffmpeg
        volumes:
            - ./music:/data
        command: ' -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "/data/image.jpeg" -i "/data/myAudio.WMA" -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "/data/myVideo.mp4" -stats'
        # command: ' -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "/data/image.jpeg" -i "/data/myAudio.mp3" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "/data/myVideo.mp4" -stats'
```

I left above my working `docker-dompose.yml` file for future readers who use docker - just run it in by `docker compose run musicToVideo` (I assume that directory ./music is in the same directory that above .yml file and it containss WMA/MP3 file and image.jpeg) (for mp3 comment 'command' with WMA and uncomment with mp3)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for FFMPEG.WASM

This code can be placed after loading ffmpeg

[Source](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/blob/master/docs/api.md#ffmpeg-setProgress)

```
ffmpeg.setProgress(({ ratio }) => {
//ratio is a float number between 0 to 1.

const progress = Math.round(ratio * 100);
// Update your progress indicator here
console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming at this late, but this is what I'm going to use, in the stderr handler:

```
import bytes from 'bytes'

function parseFfmpegError(text: string) {
  const lines = text.split(/\n/)
  if (lines[0]?.match(/File '(?:.+)' already exists\. Exiting/)) {
    return { type: 'error', text: `File already exists.` }
  } else if (
    lines[0]?.match(
      /^frame=\s*(.+)\s+fps=\s*(.+)\s+q=\s*(.+)\s+size=\s*(.+)\s+time=\s*(.+)\s+bitrate=\s*(.+)\s+speed=(.+)/,
    )
  ) {
    const { $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 } = RegExp
    const frame = parseInt($1, 10)
    const fps = parseFloat($2)
    const q = parseFloat($3)
    const size = bytes($4)
    const [t, ms] = $5.split('.')
    const [h, m, s] = t.split(':')
    const totalSeconds = parseInt(s, 10) * 1000
    const totalMinutes = parseInt(m, 10) * 60 * 1000
    const totalHours = parseInt(h, 10) * 60 * 60 * 1000
    const time = totalHours + totalMinutes + totalSeconds
    const bitrate = bytes($6.split('bits/s').shift() + 'b')
    const speed = parseFloat($7)
    return {
      type: 'progress',
      data: {
        frame,
        fps,
        q,
        size,
        time,
        bitrate,
        speed,
      },
    }
  }

  return text
}
```

Here is one frame, comes about once every second or so.

```
{
  type: 'progress',
  data: {
    frame: 14194,
    fps: 1491,
    q: 24.8,
    size: 103546880,
    time: 592000,
    bitrate: 1431552,
    speed: 62.3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `ffmpeg-progress-yield`
https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-progress-yield/
https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-progress-yield

install via `pipx`
`pipx install ffmpeg-progress-yield`
`ffmpeg-progress-yield` still works without `tqdm` and `colorama`
`pipx inject ffmpeg-progress-yield tqdm colorama`

After that, do whatever you want, starting with `ffmpeg-progress-yield` like this.
`ffmpeg-progress-yield ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4`
https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-progress-yield?tab=readme-ov-file#on-the-command-line