# How to show progressbar for FFMPEG process in java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, swt

I am merging two files using FFMPEG command in java. I want to show a progressbar for the conversion process. How can I achieve this.

FFMpeg Command:

```
ffmpeg -i audioFile -i videoFile -sameq -vcodec libx264 -r10 -ar 44100 -y -async 1 -crf 30 -b 500K outputFile
```

I am using ProcessBuilder to execute this command in a separate thread. Everything is working fine. Now I just want to show the progressbar for this process.

Could someone please guide me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on what you can find here: [Can ffmpeg show a progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747982/can-ffmpeg-show-a-progress-bar)

You should use `process.getErrorStream()` to get the stream and read in the progress information. When ever you see a progress message, you can make the respective change to your progress bar.