# ffmpeg read filesize

Tags: asp.net, ffmpeg, progress-bar, freeze

I use ffmpeg to convert a video file uploaded via an ASPX web page.
`ffmpeg` conversion works fine.

I want to provide the end-user a progress bar.
So I placed an updatPanel on my web page and tried to read the file size ...

- using **fileinfo** : ffmpeg freeze
- using **[process.start()] cmd.exe /c dir**  : ffmpeg freeze
- using **filestream** : error ->> file is used by another process
- using **ffmpeg -i X Y 2> log.txt** : log is created only when conversion completed

Whats the proper/working way to do this?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747982/can-ffmpeg-show-a-progress-bar

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I have managed to set the log. a single note for the followers, if you run ffmpeg.exe directly (ie - myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe") you cant redirect stdoutput.

Answer (score 9):

Use ffprobe command to get video metadada

Only file size:

```
ffprobe -i video.mp4 -show_entries format=size -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

Complete (return in JSON):

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams video.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to search for `duration` and progressed media `time` from ffmpeg stderr. It is a funny 'winding road' exercise of string parsing, but it saves you from using other external tools.

---

In the following, I outline how this can work, the actual code depends on the language of your choice.

**In your ffmpeg command, set `-loglevel level`:**
This will prefix the lines you are interested in with `[info]`, just to make it a little easier.

**In ffmpeg stderr, search for `duration` and `time`:**
You will need the timecode values.
This is an example of how the line for `duration` looks:

```
[info] Duration: 00:00:46.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2783 kb/s
```

This is an example of how all the lines for `time` look:

```
[info] frame=  760 fps=313 q=4.0 size=  145152kB time=00:00:31.95 bitrate=37208.5kbits/s speed=13.2x
```

**Next, you need to convert the timecode string to a value in frames or seconds.** Tip: ffmpeg uses milliseconds, which is 100 fps :-)

**The progress value is `time / duration`, which you can use to display progress, voilà!**