# shell_exec() executing before prior echo statements

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have the following code

```
<?php
       if(isset($_POST['cond']){
            echo '<br><p>Script to execute : xxxx.php<p>';
            echo "<p>Executing</p>";
            shell_exec('sleep 5');
            echo "<p>Done</p>";
       }

?>
```

Basically, the user clicks on a button that sends the 'cond' to the same page, which then enters the `if` block. I want to warn the user when the script is starting to execute, then execute the script, then warn the user that script has been executed;
the current behavior is that the `shell_exec('sleep 5')`must be executed entirely before the `echo` statements are printed to the web page.

In fact, if you take the code inside the `if` block and put in a blank page and try to load it, you have to wait the 5 seconds of sleep before the page even gets loaded, then you see the echo statements. I don't understand this behavior, PHP isn't Javascript and each line of code should be executed sequentially?

All are executed on a Debian GNU / Linux 9 remote server

Thanks in advance

Comment: did this gives you a answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500922/shell-exec-echoing-too-fast-or-too-late

Comment: yes worked perfectly, thanks. I tried to find a similar question but looks like I didnt think of the good keywords. I voted to close since its a duplicate, thanks again.

Comment: Great  it sounds good ! . thanks

Comment: For your trouble, there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['cond'])){
    echo '<br><p>Script to execute : xxxx.php<p>';
    echo "<p>Executing</p>";
    if (ob_get_length()) {
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
    }
    shell_exec('sleep 5');
    echo "<p>Done</p>";
}
```