# How may I resolve 'NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegException' error?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

The following code:

```
string pathToVideoFile = "O:\\Byblioteka\\MAH01238.MP4"; 

var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter(); 

ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(pathToVideoFile, "nowyplik.mp4", "Format.mp4");
```

Is resulting in the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegException' occurred in NReco.VideoConverter.dll
>
> Additional information: nowyplik.mp4: Invalid argument (exit code: 1)

How may I resolve this 'NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegException' error?

Comment: @DarrenYoung If you omit the path, the result file should still be created in the program's working directory. That should not cause this exception.

Comment: nowyplik.mp4 maybe it needs a fully qualified path or some odd? Also the last parameter is "type" so maybe should be like "mp4" GL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a risk answering this question since it's vague, and I don't know where you downloaded the DLL from.

But from what I know, the 3rd argument should be `"mp4"`, not `"Format.mp4"`:

```
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(pathToVideoFile, "nowyplik.mp4", "mp4");
```

This could cause this exception.

Comment: Thanks , work. Hej, mayby use % conversion video to label?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx this website example code and DLL file from downloaded

Comment: I was wondering if you could add some% conversion progress indicator eg in label

Comment: If you turn it into an async operation, you can track its progress.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747982/can-ffmpeg-show-a-progress-bar

Comment: this is no c# :(

Comment: There's no C# example online... Sorry.

Comment: And you can not present your own example for C #? And whether this AJAX is necessary - it can not be done without a web server to do

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(url, destinationThumbPath);
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(url, destinationVidoePath, Format.mp4);
```